# OSMNX How to make sure we do not plot outside of polygon

Tags: python, matplotlib, osmnx

I have the below code and it works fine, excepted that I would like to make sure water is not plotted outside of the gdf polygone as the road network.

ox.geometries_from_polygon has the right polygon as param, however it looks like OSM returns all elements if a point is within the polygon.

Any hints/examples would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Attila

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon
ox.config(log_console=True)

water_color = '#aad3df'
place = 'Budapest, Hungary'
gdf = ox.geocode_to_gdf(place)
gdf_poly = gdf["geometry"].unary_union
fp = ox.geometries_from_polygon(gdf_poly, tags={'water':['river','lake'],"natural":["water"]})

G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive', retain_all=True)

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, show=False, close=False,save=False,
                        bgcolor=None,edge_color='w' , edge_linewidth=0.3, node_size=0)

for geometry in gdf['geometry'].tolist():
    if isinstance(geometry, (Polygon, MultiPolygon)):
        if isinstance(geometry, Polygon):
            geometry = MultiPolygon([geometry])
        for polygon in geometry:
            patch = PolygonPatch(polygon, fc='#175C7D', ec='#175C7C', lw=1, alpha=1, zorder=-1)
            ax.add_patch(patch) 
            
fig, ax = ox.plot_footprints(fp,ax=ax, color=water_color, save=False, show=False)
margin = 0.02
west, south, east, north = gdf.unary_union.bounds
margin_ns = (north - south) * margin
margin_ew = (east - west) * margin
ax.set_ylim((south - margin_ns, north + margin_ns))
ax.set_xlim((west - margin_ew, east + margin_ew))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just take the intersection of your water geometries and the place boundary like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon
ox.config(log_console=True)

water_color = '#aad3df'
place = 'Budapest, Hungary'
gdf = ox.geocode_to_gdf(place)
place_poly = gdf.unary_union

fp = ox.geometries_from_polygon(place_poly, tags={'water':['river','lake'],"natural":["water"]})
water_poly = fp[fp.geometry.geom_type.str.contains('Polygon')].unary_union.intersection(place_poly)

G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive', retain_all=True)

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, show=False, close=False,save=False,
                        bgcolor=None,edge_color='w' , edge_linewidth=0.3, node_size=0)

ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(place_poly, fc='#175C7D', ec='#175C7C', lw=1, alpha=1, zorder=-1))
ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(water_poly, fc=water_color, ec=water_color))

margin = 0.02
west, south, east, north = gdf.unary_union.bounds
margin_ns = (north - south) * margin
margin_ew = (east - west) * margin
ax.set_ylim((south - margin_ns, north + margin_ns))
ax.set_xlim((west - margin_ew, east + margin_ew))
plt.show()
```